# Windows batch: How to search path of executable and store in variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following script that should search the path to a variable and store it in a variable:

```
FOR %%i IN (app.exe) DO (
    SET app=%%~$PATH:i 
    ECHO %app%
)
```

But the output of echo is empty, no matter if i ECHO within or outside of the for loop. What am i missing?

Comment: Does `set app=%%~dpi` work?

Comment: What about `where "app.exe"`? to capture the output, do `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%A in ('where "app.exe"') do (set "APP=%%A)"`. Anyway, `echo %APP%` must be outside of the loop, hence beyond the last `)`!

Comment: @Regejok, I think the OP wants to find `app.exe` via the `PATH` variable; the `~dp` modifier only returns the *current directory* independent on the true location of `app.exe`, because `for` does not even access the file system when the file set does not contain any global wild-cards (`*`, `?`)...

Comment: Moving the `echo` outside the loop works for me.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) if you want to print the result within the brackets range:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i IN (app.exe) DO (
    SET "app=%%~$PATH:i" 
    ECHO !app!
)
```

you can also use `where` [command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('where app.exe') do set "app=%%a"
echo %app%
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, somehow i managed to remove the app.exe directory from my system PATH Environment variable. I readded it and now it works...